# How to make Python go back to asking for input

Tags: python, loops, input, line, back

So I want the program to go back to asking for the input once it has completed.

I've asked this in reddit and gone through quite a many similar threads here and so far the answer seems to be loops if true perform x. But what is the command for the program to go back to asking for the input on line 5?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

card = input()

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.mtgprice.com/")
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form/input")
elem.send_keys(card) # input
driver.implicitly_wait(5) # seconds
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn-blue').click()
```

Comment: Go back from where? Have you tried putting a while loop in? Do you want it to stop ever?https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop

Answer (score 2):

Everyone you asked is pretty much right. Additionally I'd put the chunk of code in a function just because.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

def web_stuff(card):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("http://www.mtgprice.com/")
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form/input")
    elem.send_keys(card) # input
    driver.implicitly_wait(5) # seconds
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn-blue').click()


while loop_condition:
    card = input()
    web_stuff(card)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't say what you want to happen over and over again and if you ever want to stop, a starting point is just to put all the driver code into a loop:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

while True:
    card = input()

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("http://www.mtgprice.com/")
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form/input")
    elem.send_keys(card) # input
    driver.implicitly_wait(5) # seconds
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn-blue').click()
```

Comment: Ok thanks that's it. I guess I didn't just know how to apply it.

I just want it to do the search function on and on.